# local core data store with icloud

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud

I have a question regarding icloud store with core data store in iOS7. In the apple WWDC conference, it was mentioned that the core data store can be created in the sandbox and when the app starts receiving responses from icloud, the changes in the core data store will be merged into icloud store.

Now, (I might be wrong), but the conference further mentioned that the local core data store would be deleted once the app has switched over to the icloud store. So, my question is can a local core data store co-exist with the icloud store in iOS7  (so that the user has capability to work offline with data) ? And is there any sample code for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 7, the Core Data framework takes care of managing the local store until the iCloud store is setup and available. This pattern also works for when the app is offline and it doesn't delete any data when the app goes offline (just double checked on my app in development).

The iCloud store will be deleted in another case. That's in the event the iCloud user account changes in which case the respective iCloud store file will be removed. In such case, there is a new API `NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorStoresWillChangeNotification` that allows you to store unsaved data before the store becomes unavailable. If the user logs in later with that same account, the data will be restored from iCloud (check the WWDC 2013 session 207 video at 15' for more on this).

As for sample code, there isn't any as of today. There is, though, [iCloud sample code shared by AppleSpaceMan](https://devforums.apple.com/thread/201492?tstart=0) on the developer forum, which is what I used as a base and worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can work offline(no network connection) with the iCloud store as long as you have an iCloud account and are logged in to that account.  I have just posted a sample application that includes the following features:

- Use of ***Local*** or ***iCloud*** Core Data store
- *Includes a* ***Settings Bundle*** (note that this creates a settings page in the Settings App) that includes:

  - *Use iCloud* preference setting (ON or OFF)
  - *Make Backup* preference setting (ON or OFF)
  - Display application *Version* and *Build Number*
- ***Prompts the user about storage options*** when the **Use iCloud** preference is changed to ON
- ***Migrates Core Data store to and from iCloud*** depending on the users preference setting and response to prompts
- ***Detects deletion of iCloud store from another device*** and cleans up by creating a new empty iCloud store
- ***Checks for existing iCloud files when migrating*** local store to iCloud and prompts user whether to merge or discard data in local store if an iCloud file exists
- ***Makes a Backup*** of the Core Data store if **Make Backup** preference is set to ON.  Backup file name is **persistentStore_Backup_yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss.** To use it:
  - set Backup preference ON and next time the app is activated it will make a backup of the current Core Data store and reset the preference to OFF
  - file can be copied to PC or Mac from iTunes
  - to restore simply set app to use Local files (**Use iCloud** preference OFF) and replace the **persistentStore** file with the required backup file (note the file must be called ***persistentStore***).
  - to then share restored file via iCloud again turn **Use iCloud** preference to ON and run App

http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/